# Get Name From Another Table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table in my database called

> number_list and number_status

I am currently getting perfect result using below query

```
SELECT * FROM number_status 
WHERE number = '".$_SESSION['number1']."' OR 
      number = '".$_SESSION['number2']."'  
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Now I want name from table number_list. Both table have number is common. I have tried some Left Join etc but I am learning MySQL yet so not getting proper result. Let me know if someone can help me for do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join query as follows

```
SELECT s.id, s.number, l.name FROM number_list l JOIN number_status s ON l.number=s.number   WHERE s.number = '".$_SESSION['number1']."' OR s.number = '".$_SESSION['number2']."'  ORDER BY l.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

or you can directly get the name as you have the number in hand as follows

```
SELECT name FROM number_list WHERE number = '".$_SESSION['number1']."' OR number = '".$_SESSION['number2']."'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```